# Why does this controller not work properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is the first time I'm deployng an Ruby on Rails app on my VPS.

My server is running Ubuntu 11.04 with ruby 1.9.2, Rails and Passenger.

I made a simple app with the automatic scaffold and I've placed it in /home/rails/myapp.

In the apache configuration file I've written:

```
Listen 888
NameVirtualHost *:888

<VirtualHost *:888>

    RailsEnv production
    DocumentRoot /home/rails/myapp/public
    <Directory /home/rails/myapp/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This way I can access the app through my server's port 888.

As you can see, the controller I've made [seems to work properly](http://maurovps.no-ip.org:888/posts) but I get an error message when I try to save a record.

The log file does not say anything about this error.

So, what could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the db on your server? If not use db migrations.

Comment: are you pushing your app on heroku?

Comment: Nope, I've my own virtual private server!

Comment: Did you check the log file? It might give some help.

Comment: Both log/production.log and log/develpment.log has nothing inside.
If I save some records using the rails console everything works fine. But even if the records has been saved (and I can retrive them using the console) the index action of the controller who should list each entry does not show anything.

I think there is some database issue..

Comment: You should enable logging, which is set by default. You could save time in finding a solution to a error by looking at the log. I guess the problem might be with the query. Re-check the query you're running.

Comment: And do not enable error logging on a production system. Missed that point.

Comment: Enabling logging I've found that the db directory was read-only. Changing the permission solved the issue